# ¿Cómo hacer que un fragment al recuperarlo la información que contenia no se pierde en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Como se puede hacer que al volver a un fragment que ya se había cargado y usado su interfaz, al volver a el, mantenga los cambios.

Me encuentro que al cargar el fragment siempre se inicia de 0

Layout con un checkbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Primer fragmento" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OneFragment**

```
public static class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    public static FirstFragment newInstance() {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView: FirstFragment");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

Y lo cargo con esa función

```
private void openFragment(int frameContainer, Fragment newFragment) {

    String loadFragmentName = newFragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(frameContainer);

    if (currentFragment == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "openFragment: ADD" + loadFragmentName + " in stack");
        ft.add(frameContainer, newFragment);
    } else {

        if (!currentFragment.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase(loadFragmentName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "openFragment: REPLACE" + loadFragmentName + " in stack");

            ft.replace(frameContainer, newFragment);
            //ft.addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName());

        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "openFragment: NO REPLACE");
        }

    }

    ft.commit();

}
```

Comment: Utiliza .hide and .show para los fragments, solo que tendrías que crear un Stack si no quieres iniciar el fragment dos veces, una vez abierto solo tienes que buscar el fragment en el stack y ordenar el stack poniendo como peek() el nuevo fragment. Te compartiré un poco de mi código.

Comment: He encontrado eso, que hay apartado de fragments, https://github.com/Blankj/AndroidUtilCode

Comment: :o muchas gracias por esa información @Webserveis, me servirá bastante a mi tambien, muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo bueno de mi código es que puedo hacer OnResume y OnPause, así puedo hacer update de la información que contiene el Fragment y remover y agregar listeners que no se están utilizando.

Comment: @Andrespengineer mírate mi respuesta, he implementado un sistema de carga de fragments y que si existe ya el fragment pues oculta o muestra dependiendo si es necesario, los datos  checkbox de cada fragment en mis prueba han permitido intactos.

Answer (score 1):

```
private TuPrimerFragment tuPrimerFragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack;
```

Tengo un stack para manejar los fragments y el onBackPressed, esto va en el `OnCreate`:

```
fragmentStack = new Stack<>();

tuPrimerFragment = new TuPrimerFragment();
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment, tuPrimerFragment);
fragmentStack.push(tuPrimerFragment);
ft.commit();
```

Crea este método y llamalo cuando vayas a crear el fragment en un onItemClick o algo asi si estas usando el navigation drawer:

```
public void ShowFragments(String tag, Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
        fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentStack.lastElement());
        fragmentStack.push(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

En el onBackPressed:

```
if (fragmentStack.size() >= 2) {
       FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
       ft.remove(fragmentStack.pop());
       fragmentStack.lastElement().onResume();
       ft.show(fragmentStack.lastElement()); }
else{
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Ya solo tienes que validar que si el fragment ya existe en el Stack, ponerlo como Peek y hacer un sort del Stack, yo aún no lo he implementado porque he estado ocupado en otras funcionalidades de mi app.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al comentario de @Andrespengineer que existe la opción de mostrar y ocultar los fragments he sacado eso:

Crear una variable estática para que el valor permanezca si se rota el dispositivo.

`private static String oldFragmentTAG = null;`

Función toggle para mostrar o ocultar un fragment extraido de [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29230278/3464919) modificado.

```
public void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out);

        if (fragment.isHidden()) {
            ft.show(fragment);
        } else {
            ft.hide(fragment);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Mi función openDialog() modificada para que cargue el fragment si no está en la pila y si está pues lo muestre de nuevo. También tiene sistema de prevención de cargar de nuevo y mostrar el fragment que está visible.

```
private void openFragment(int frameContainer, Fragment newFragment) {

    String loadFragmentName = newFragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(frameContainer);

    if (currentFragment == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "openFragment: ADD" + loadFragmentName + " in stack");
        ft.add(frameContainer, newFragment, loadFragmentName);
        ft.commit();
        oldFragmentTAG = loadFragmentName;
    } else {

        if (!oldFragmentTAG.equalsIgnoreCase(loadFragmentName)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "openFragment: REPLACE" + loadFragmentName + " in stack");

            if (fm.findFragmentByTag(loadFragmentName) == null) {
                ft.add(frameContainer, newFragment, loadFragmentName);
                ft.commit();
            }

            showHideFragment(fm.findFragmentByTag(oldFragmentTAG));
            showHideFragment(fm.findFragmentByTag(loadFragmentName));

            //ft.addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName());
            oldFragmentTAG = loadFragmentName;
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "openFragment: NO REPLACE");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Excelente. ¿Que tal te funciona el OnBackPressed, como lo implementaste?

Comment: No la implementado aun, mirare a ver como se comporta añadiendo fragments al backstack

Comment: Ok, cuando lo implementes si puedes edita tu respuesta y déjame saber.